# xarray dt.date / dt.normalize missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, python-xarray

In xarray the `.dt` [DatetimeAccessor accessor](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html) doesn't have a [`.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) attribute or [`.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) method, is this normal ?

What are the equivalents in xarray to convert a timestamp to a date only ? Using [`.dt.strftime()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.strftime.html#xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.strftime) then convert ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal; xarray does not currently implement those methods.  `.dt.floor(“D”)` should effectively do the same thing as `normalize` however.  Would that suffice for your needs?

Comment: Thanks a lot it's what I need ! Do you happen to know why it's not implemented yet ?

Comment: There is not a particularly good reason -- these methods would be fairly straightforward to add -- it's just that it has not been a priority.